# Updating field in attribute table of multiple shapefiles in ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: field-calculator, attribute-table

I have almost 100 shapefiles (all having polyline features only) in a single folder with each filename "0","1"..."99" . I need to recalculate the length and another field "slope" which I previously calculated in field calculator:

`slope =`

```
math.degrees(math.atan(100/ !Length! ))".
```

Now I want to recalculate both fields in each shapefile.
PS: These 100 shapefiles were previously one shapefile whose length and slope has been calculated. But there after I clipped it using features of another shapefile resulting into 100 shapefiles. But the length and slope value was not get upated and it is showing the old values of the single shape file. Now I want to calculate slope and length again for each shapefile which is time consuming so I hope something can be done in a Model Builder or a Python script which could ease my computation.

Comment: Which software are you working with? You seem to know how to calculate your desired output, since you already did it - so what is your question?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  As it stands I think your question would benefit from being revised to try and make what you are asking clearer.  I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for tips on how to structure a good question.

Comment: @Erik. I did this in Arc GIS 10.1 and these 100 shapefiles were previously one shape file whose length and slope has been calculated. But there after I clipped it using features of another shapefile resulting into 100 shapefiles. But the length and slope value was not get updated and it is showing the old values of the single shape file

Comment: ArcGIS 10.1 is so old it has to be considered a different product from the 10.7.1/10.8.x on modern desktops.  The Python implementation was virtually non-existent compared to the current state. You're not going to be able to get much assistance with long-retired software, even if you invest in the time tp write an initial attempt at code.

Comment: @Vince Okay will consider the new version, but new version has any built in tool to perform my requirement?

Comment: It's a 10-line script that you're seeking, seven of which are already in the documentation. There's no reason to publish such a specific tool.

Comment: Or no lines of Script @Vince, this can be easily knocked up with model builder and an [iterator](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Examples_of_using_iterators_in_ModelBuilder/00400000001n000000/ESRI_SECTION1_46903073A36D4E928AAFC0F0AE5240EC/) linked to a couple of field calculate tools.